# Which layout we have to use to place the text view and edit text at what ever position we want in android?

Tags: android, layout

We are working on android project. We have placed background image with Relative Layout. Now we want to place username and password with login button. Which layout we should use now? We are facing some problems in keeping those at our required position. **What properties we have to set?** Please send us sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think RelativeLayout is best according your requirement ..

[all layout sample code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

plz see this link try to implement using relativelayout.

[property of relative layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:background="@drawable/log1" 

>

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/l1"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  
   
  </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

First, make a layout xml similar to this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/marker_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
</RelativeLayout>
```

After that, instantiate a RelativeLayout base on that xml

```
 RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.marker_layout);
```

From now on, just add your textview to rl with paramLayout like this.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 param.leftMargin = your desired x coor;
 param.topMargin = your desired y coor;
 rl.addView(TextView,param);
```